# How should I add glyphicons Bootstrapin the address bar? (favicon)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for my english. I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.6, I do not know how to use glyphicons Bootstrap favicon, already tried Many ways

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking "Bootstrap", "Favicon" and "Glyphicons" are 3 seperate, unrelated and independent things.  I can assume you want to use one in another, but it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: favicon = Favorite Icon.
Bootstrap = framework.
glyphicons = icon library.
everyone is united in a project.
http://getbootstrap.com/components/
I desire to use a Glyphicons in the address bar
Bootstrap has included more than 250 for use.

Comment: Address bar of the browser????  You can't:  Glyphicons is a font... in html content you can set a font, but the browser UI (outside the content) uses the OS system fonts, can't be changed from the html content.

Comment: Now I understand , so I could not , thank you friend . I will make gliphicons package dounload in png and add in my project .

Comment: That will work.  Also, if you go to the FA GitHub repo you can grab the SVG versions of the icons, and use that to convert to a graphic.

Answer (score 3):

I'll quote [Josh Harrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/940252/josh-harrison), but I have the same opinion  :

The bootstrap icons are from [Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/), and their free download package includes the bootstrap cloud icon as a PNG. You will need to make this into a 16x16 px (normal res) or 32x32 px (for retina) png, which will then be good to reference as you already know how:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/cloud.png">
```

Comment: If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions.